# django sendgrid get error when sending email

Tags: django, smtp, sendgrid

I set up sendgrid as following and it works perfectly when I use send_mail to send a test message

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '******'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Howerver when I implement it with an activation code in views.py for registration as bellow:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() #completed sign up
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            # Create data in profile table for user
            current_user = request.user
            data=UserProfile()
            data.user_id=current_user.id
            data.image="images/users/user.png"
            data.save()

            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Please Activate Your Account'
            # load a template like get_template() 
            # and calls its render() method immediately.
            message = render_to_string('user/activation_request.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                # method will generate a hash value with user related data
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject, message)
            return redirect('activation_sent')   
            # messages.success(request, 'Your account has been created!')
            # return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            messages.warning(request,form.errors)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register')


    form = SignUpForm()
    #category = Category.objects.all()
    context = {
               'form': form,
               }
    return render(request, 'user/register.html', context)
```

It throws out this error:

```
SMTPDataError at /register
(550, b'The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved. Visit https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/ to see the Sender Identity requirements')
```

I have verified the sender and that's why It works with send_mail but it doesn't work with activation code.

Please someone have a look for me.

Thanks

Comment: Please show `user.email_user()`

Comment: Hello, it does come from user.email_user(), I forgot to include my sender email, thanks

Comment: Hi Knight, if you have enough points, answer your own question and accept the answer. It keeps others from reviewing only to find it has a solution already. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is missing sender email in following code:

```
user.email_user(subject, message)
```

It should be:

```
user.email_user(subject, message,"email@example.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sendgrid requires to setup sender before you're able to send email.

Go to your sendgrid management page (https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/sender_auth) and create a sender. A sender must be verified.

Then django, you can set default email in settings.py

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = <your sendgrid sender>
```